# Using indexOf() in Switch Statement

Tags: javascript

Need to set variable values using a Switch Statement based on a string being present in the URL. I've accomplished this by using if/then statements but I now need a "default" for var3. It would be cumbersome to write a final if/then statement that basically says that the final condition is met when none of the other strings are found in dom.url.

Preferably, I'd want something like this:

```
if b.event_name ==="form_completion" {
    switch(b['dom.url'].indexOf(MYSTRING)) {
        case "Req-Quote-Thanks-Modal") > -1:
            b.var1 = "VAL1";
            b.var2 = "VAL2";
            b.var3 = "VAL3";
        break;
        deafult:
            b.var1 = "VAL1-Default";
            b.var2 = "VAL2-Default"; 
            b.var3 = "VAL3-Default"; 
        }
}
```

I've tired a series of if/then statements and case statements with if/then statements

```
if (b.event_name === "form_completion" && b['dom.url'].indexOf("Req-Quote-Thanks-Modal") > -1) 
    {
        b.var1 = "VAL1";
        b.var2 = "VAL2";
        b.var3 = "VAL3";
    }
else if (b.event_name === "form_completion" && b['dom.pathname'].indexOf("sweeps-thank-you") >-1)
    {
        b.var1 = "VAL1";
        b.var2 = "VAL2";
        b.var3 = "VAL4";
    }
else if (b.event_name === "form_completion" && b['dom.pathname'].indexOf("special-offers-thank-you") >-1)
    {
        b.var1 = "VAL1";
        b.var2 = "VAL2";
        b.var3 = "VAL5";
    }
else if (b.event_name === "form_completion" && b['dom.pathname'].indexOf("brochure") >-1 && b['dom.pathname'].indexOf("thank-you") >-1)
    {
        b.var1 = "VAL1";
        b.var2 = "VAL2";
        b.var3 = "VAL6";
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can execute the indexOf as you pass it into the switch, regardless you could do indexOf first then pass the result to your switch ... the result will be a number! -1, 0, 1 ...

Comment: Maybe you could just describe what you want in words, because the way you've described it in code is confusing to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can but it will be better to use if statements.

Anyway, here's the way how to implement with switch.

```
switch(true) {
 case b['dom.url'].indexOf("Req-Quote-Thanks-Modal") > -1:
   b.var1 = "VAL1";
   b.var2 = "VAL2";
   b.var3 = "VAL3";
   break;
 case b['dom.pathname'].indexOf("sweeps-thank-you") >-1):
   b.var1 = "VAL1";
   b.var2 = "VAL2";
   b.var3 = "VAL4";
   break;
 case b['dom.pathname'].indexOf("special-offers-thank-you") >-1:
   b.var1 = "VAL1";
   b.var2 = "VAL2";
   b.var3 = "VAL5";
   break;
 case b['dom.pathname'].indexOf("brochure") >-1 && b['dom.pathname'].indexOf("thank-you") >-1):
   b.var1 = "VAL1";
   b.var2 = "VAL2";
   b.var3 = "VAL6";
   break;
 default:
   // here is the other condition
   break;
}
```

Comment: Apparently I was voted down significantly and told I was unclear in my question but you've answered it entirely so I thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that with a `switch` statement, unless the string consists entirely of the value to match against. You can however still simplify your code a lot:

```
if (b.event_name === "form_completion") {
    b.var1 = "VAL1";
    b.var2 = "VAL2";
    var pathname = b['dom.pathname'];
    if (b['dom.url'].includes("Req-Quote-Thanks-Modal")) 
        b.var3 = "VAL3";
    } else if (pathname.includes("sweeps-thank-you")) {
        b.var3 = "VAL4";
    } else if (pathname.includes("special-offers-thank-you")) {
        b.var3 = "VAL5";
    } else if (pathname.includes("brochure") && pathname.includes("thank-you")) {
        b.var3 = "VAL6";
    }
}
```

<sub>(This is not exactly equivalent to your code, as it assigns to `var1` and `var2` as soon as the event name matches, even if none of the inner conditions is met. I can update the code if you need this changed.)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

From your example, it looks like var1 and var2 have the same values in any case, so you don't have to repeat those if you just pull them out of the conditions. You're also checking that the event_name is form_completion in every condition, so you can pull that up, too, resulting in this code:

```
if (b.event_name === "form_completion") {
    b.var1 = "VAL1";
    b.var2 = "VAL2";
    if (b['dom.url'].indexOf("Req-Quote-Thanks-Modal") > -1) 
    {
        b.var3 = "VAL3";
    }
    else if (b['dom.pathname'].indexOf("sweeps-thank-you") >-1)
    {
        b.var3 = "VAL4";
    }
    else if (b['dom.pathname'].indexOf("special-offers-thank-you") >-1)
    {
        b.var3 = "VAL5";
    }
    else if (b['dom.pathname'].indexOf("brochure") >-1 && b['dom.pathname'].indexOf("thank-you") >-1)
    {
        b.var3 = "VAL6";
    }
}
```

You could also possibly map the pathname options to the var3 values in an object and iterate through that, but I don't think that will actually make your code any more concise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex like this:

```
if b.event_name ==="form_completion" {
   switch(true) {
    case /Req-Quote-Thanks-Modal/.test(b['dom.url']):
        b.var1 = "VAL1";
        b.var2 = "VAL2";
        b.var3 = "VAL3";
    break;
    deafult:
        b.var1 = "VAL1-Default";
        b.var2 = "VAL2-Default"; 
        b.var3 = "VAL3-Default"; 
    }
}
```